# I am getting 0 values for my array when I try to add DOM elements from a webpage, how to add values to lists in .each function?

Tags: append, each, appendto

On console it presents just empty array and 0's for all the elements on the Business Insider page with the specific selectors. How can I add each number (which is views on their site) as a list or string of numbers and then .length on the variable and push it to my html interface?

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var bilist = new Array();
//var x = document.getElementById('bi-stats').innerHTML;

    var url = 'http://www.businessinsider.com/moneygame';
    request(url, function(err,resp,body) 
    {


            if (err)
                throw err;
            $ = cheerio.load(body); //create the dom object string
            $('span.hot').each(function() {
                $(this).text().append(bilist);
                console.log(bilist);
                console.log(bilist.length);


            });  
        }); 


function start() {        
        window.addEventListener('load', bi_list(), false);
}
```

Comment: Your `var bilist` is an empty array. Why should be elements inside?

Comment: Hi Felippe basically I got confused of jQuery's version of a for iterator which is the .each(function(i, elem) {};    I solved it thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So jQuery has a different syntax for the 'for' iterator.

The correct code is shown below which appends the text element that contains # of views of the site Business Insider.

```
$('span.hot').each(function(i, elem) {
            bilist[i] = $(this).text();

       });
```